# call php function when browser back button clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I call a **`PHP Function`** when `Browser Back button` clicked or `right click` then clicked BACK item then prevent page to redirect to `login page` when user is still `logged-in`.

I found this [**`(Pressing back button redirects the logged user to log out?)`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152052/pressing-back-button-redirects-the-logged-user-to-log-out) to prevent page to redirect to other page when user clicked **`browser back button`** and user is still logged in, but I didn't know where to put those codes and how to call that function.

Can someone explain this thoroughly to accomplish my problem or provide some `DEMO`(JSFiddle) for better understanding?

Comment: There is no reliable way to do what you want.

Comment: Do you need this only on a certain page or whenever the back button is pressed or the back event fires in the browser?

Comment: @AresDraguna only specific page(one page only).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a header redirect on the login page to check if the user is logged in, but this will have to be called before any page data is sent:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("Location: home.php");
}
```

Comment: I imagine he's handling the login on the index page which is why he sees the 'page expired' message when he hits back. but using a separate login page and a redirect is a better approach +1

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

    window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');

    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
      alert('Back button was pressed.'); //here you know that the back button is pressed
    });

  }
});
```

You can find the answer **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594413/js-or-jquery-browser-back-button-click-detector)**

What this does, it checks with JS if the back button was pushed and if so, you can perform whatever action you want. If a redirect is what you need, use `window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";` OR `window.navigate("http://www.yoururl.com"); //works only with IE`

Alternatively, you can place an jquery ajax call there, that sends posted requests back to a certain page, and you can check them like:

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax_response_from_js_script'])  {
    //call PHP function
}
```

Hope it helps!

Keep on coding!

Ares.

Comment: i tried your code and it works to different browsers but except for Safari Windows(v5.1.7)